# retrieving and plotting data over time

Tags: php, mysql, excel, data-visualization

I run into this problem again and again;

**Situation**
there is a (large) dataset with records tied to a date (or even time) and I have the need to plot this data over time.

**Problem**
The dataset only contains the dates for which there are records available (obviously), but I need also the 'empty' dates to be able to plot multiple series evenly over time.

**Tools**
I usually work with MySQL and PHP, most often pasting the data into Excel to plot graphs etc.

**Workaround**
Up till this moment I usually create an excel sheet and put in the dates by hand and determine the appropriate number of results with a SumIf on the dataset. 
This seems a bit stupid to me though, and isn't really workable when working with a lot of records (excel gets really REALLY slow quite quickly).

I'm really curious to see if there isn't a 'real' and better solution to do this, maybe already in the construction of the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are dates in you excel data text that look like dates, or date serial numbers formatted to display as dates?

If the date data points are date serial numbers then the plot will space the X axis evenly over time irrespective of interval between individual data points

The attached image demontrates: the first column and plot are "Dates" stored as text, the second date serial numbers formatted as dates

[image: Demo of Plot]

Comment: I know how this is supposed to work, but somehow I end up fighting with the formatting of the date more often than i'd like :P

Answer (score 1):

One obvious solution would be to create a table containing every date in the range and select your data left joined to this:

```
  CREATE TABLE days ( day DATE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY day );
  INSERT INTO days (day) VALUES (20110101);
  INSERT INTO days (day) VALUES (20110102);
  ....
  SELECT days.day, yourtable.*
  FROM days LEFT JOIN yourtable
     ON days.day=yourtable.day;
```

Alternatively you could inject the missing days using PHP (but I think jupaju's code is rather flawed):

```
  // ensure your qry returns DATE_FORMAT(day, '%Y-%m-%d') AS day
  $lastday='';
  while ($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($qry_result)) {
      if (!$lastday) $lastday=$r['day'];
      while ($r['day']>$lastday) {
          print $lastday . "\n";
          $lastday=add_day($lastday);
      }
      unset($r['day']);
      print $lastday . ',' . implode(',', $r) . "\n";
  }

  function add_day($day)
  {
     list($yr, $mo, $da)=explode('-',$day);
     $t=mktime(4,0,0,$mo, $da, $yr)+24*60*60; // NB not all days are 24 hours
     return date('Y-m-d',$t);
  }
```

Comment: still feels a bit like a workaround, but I like the idea. Gonna try this, thx! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP I would do something like this (assuming db-results are in `$res` having date as `Y-m-d` as key):

```
$year = date('Y');
for ($month = 1; $month <= 12; $month++) {
    $last_day = date('t', mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, $month, $year));
    for ($day = 1; $day <= $last_day; $day++) {
        $key = sprintf('%4d-%02d-%02d', $year, $month, $day);
        if (!empty($res[$key])) {
            $output[$key] = $res[$key];
        } else {
            $output[$key] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

That way you'll get an array `$output` with empty dates having value `0`.